# how to view an html file in browser using simplecov gem

Tags: html, browser, rubygems

I'm using simplecov gem, I follow the link [here](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) the build and installation for simplecov is completed. When running the spec test, it runns successfuly and display message as generate full coverage of rails project.And i found  the  index.html file is created under coverage folder.

How to i view the index.html in my browser. I use metrical gem. For i sake metrcs_fu is not supported in ruby 1.9.2 version. What is the other option to see my application in browser.

Answer (score 5):

You can view this by just open the index.html as local file like this:

> file:///home/username/code_folder/project_name/coverage/index.html

Comment: Or run `open coverage/index.html` from the root directory (having run tests) to get an overview of the coverage across the entire directory.